# Pandas/Numpy - Data cleaning- importing csv, - export to csv loses variable entries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dataframe

I want to import three large excel files as .CSV into pandas and concatenate them. They all have 128 variables ( some Int, some categorical, some strings and some dates.) and 200,000 records.

I get a 'DtypeWarning: Columns (124,125,126,127) have mixed types'. This is not really a problem as the last four fields are mainly empty.

I have imported the 3 .csv's using pandas.read_csv().This gives me df1,df2,df3. All well and no loss of data.

- to show the numeric columns

```
df4_numeric = df4.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
numeric_cols = df4_numeric.columns.values
print(numeric_cols)

['fyear' 'ADMIAGE' 'ADMINCAT' 'ADMISORC' 'CLASSPAT' 'NNAP_CONSULT'
 'DISDEST' 'DISMETH' 'EPIKEY' 'EPIORDER' 'EPISTAT' 'EPITYPE' 'IMD04'
 'IMD04HD' 'INTMANIG' 'MAINSPEF' 'SEX' 'STARTAGE' 'SUSSPELLID']
```

- and to show the non numeric columns

```
df4_non_numeric = df4.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])
non_numeric_cols = df4_non_numeric.columns.values
print(non_numeric_cols)

['ADMIDATE' 'ADMIMETH' 'DIAG_01' 'DIAG_02' 'DIAG_03' 'DIAG_04' 'DIAG_05'
 'DIAG_06' 'DIAG_07' 'DIAG_08' 'DIAG_09' 'DIAG_10' 'DIAG_11' 'DIAG_12'
 'DIAG_13' 'DIAG_14' 'DIAG_15' 'DIAG_16' 'DIAG_17' 'DIAG_18' 'DIAG_19'
 'DIAG_20' 'Diag_4_01' 'DISDATE' 'DOMPROC' 'ENCRYPTED_HESID' 'EPIEND'
 'EPISTART' 'ETHNOS' 'LSOA01' 'LSOA11' 'OPDATE_01' 'OPDATE_02' 'OPDATE_03'
 'OPDATE_04' 'OPDATE_05' 'OPDATE_06' 'OPDATE_07' 'OPDATE_08' 'OPDATE_09'
 'OPDATE_10' 'OPDATE_11' 'OPDATE_12' 'OPDATE_13' 'OPDATE_14' 'OPDATE_15'
 'OPDATE_16' 'OPDATE_17' 'OPDATE_18' 'OPDATE_19' 'OPDATE_20' 'OPDATE_21'
 'OPDATE_22' 'OPDATE_23' 'OPDATE_24' 'OPERTN_01' 'OPERTN_02' 'OPERTN_03'
 'OPERTN_04' 'OPERTN_05' 'OPERTN_06' 'OPERTN_07' 'OPERTN_08' 'OPERTN_09'
 'OPERTN_10' 'OPERTN_11' 'OPERTN_12' 'OPERTN_13' 'OPERTN_14' 'OPERTN_15'
 'OPERTN_16' 'OPERTN_17' 'OPERTN_18' 'OPERTN_19' 'OPERTN_20' 'OPERTN_21'
 'OPERTN_22' 'OPERTN_23' 'OPERTN_24' 'OPERTN_4_01' 'POSTDIST' 'PROCODE5'
 'SITETRET' 'TRETSPEF' 'DOD' 'opertn_01Type' 'opertn_02Type'
 'opertn_03Type' 'opertn_04Type' 'opertn_05Type' 'opertn_06Type'
 'opertn_07Type' 'opertn_08Type' 'opertn_09Type' 'opertn_10Type'
 'opertn_11Type' 'opertn_12Type' 'opertn_13Type' 'opertn_14Type'
 'opertn_15Type' 'opertn_16Type' 'opertn_17Type' 'opertn_18Type'
 'opertn_19Type' 'opertn_20Type' 'opertn_21Type' 'opertn_22Type'
 'opertn_23Type' 'opertn_24Type']
```

just eyeballing the data there is no loss of the data fields and I used

```
cols = df4.columns[:128] # all variables
colours = ['#000099', '#ffff00'] # specify the colours - yellow is missing. blue is not missing.
sns.heatmap(df4[cols].isnull(), cmap=sns.color_palette(colours))
```

[image: heatmap to show concatenated .csv x 3] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgdoj.png)

So I don't think I have lost any data. This is the correct picture. The data is hospital surgical activivity data and there are many empty fields, - eg the records relate to a single admission to hospital and there are sufficient variable to allow description of 25 operations (god forbid), 25 operation dates, 25 diagnoses etc and most patients will only have a few (1-4).
I eventually want to pull this df4 into Stata.

- However, -when I export this df4 ( concatenated df1,df2,df3) back to a csv the csv loses entries in about a third of the column variables. (see heatmap below)

If I then re-import the .csv back into pandas, I get the following Dtype error

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (3,4,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,34,35,38,41,45,46,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,100,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import
```

[[image: heatmap for reimported concat .csv] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmzB.png)

I suspect the way to do this is to clean the columns on entry and possibly drop some columns though I don't think that is the problem.I'd like to know the best way to define the variable data types on import, - I don't know how to do that, other than going through them all in Excel?

The heatmap shows the loss of dta is in the first dataframe (df1) 
- the one that gave the dtype error of variable 124,125,126 and 127. When imported and concatenated this did not have any dta missing so it must be due to the export to csv.

The problematic dataframe is the one with values that are lost - (=df1)
pd.read_csv complained about the last 4 columns having mixed dtype so I changed the dtype

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/....base_data/2014_2013.csv',sep=',', dtype={'opertn_21Type': str,
                                                                                         'opertn_22Type': str,
                                                                                         'opertn_23Type': str,
                                                                                         'opertn_24Type': str})
```

df1.head()

```
fyear     ADMIDATE ADMIMETH  ADMINCAT  ADMISORC  CLASSPAT  \
0        2014          29/07/2014       22         1        19         1   
1        2014         06/06/2014       12         1        19         1   
2        2014         23/06/2014       11         1        19         1   
3        2014         19/07/2014       2B         1        51         1   
4        2014        12/12/2014       11         1        19         1   
      ...      ...         ...      ...       ...       ...       ...   
202451   2013       32  22/04/2013       21         1        19         1   
202452   2013       80  12/06/2013       28         1        51         1   
202453   2013       60  01/08/2013       21         1        19         1   
202454   2013       25  22/03/2013       21         1        19         1   
202455   2013       33  06/08/2013       11         1        19         1   

        NNAP_CONSULT DIAG_01 DIAG_02  ... opertn_15Type opertn_16Type  \
0                921   R69X6     NaN  ...           NaN           NaN   
1                319   R69X6     NaN  ...           NaN           NaN   
2                861    Z438    Z538  ...           NaN           NaN   
3                327   R69X6     NaN  ...           NaN           NaN   
4               1058   M512-   M4806  ...           NaN           NaN   
             ...     ...     ...  ...           ...           ...   
202451           738    O994    I630  ...           NaN           NaN   
202452           788    D320    G401  ...           NaN           NaN   
202453           471   S1210    G20X  ...           NaN           NaN   
202454           420   S3200    I269  ...           NaN           NaN   
202455           354   D320-   H549-  ...           NaN           NaN   

       opertn_17Type opertn_18Type opertn_19Type opertn_20Type opertn_21Type  \
0                NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
1                NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
2                NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
3                NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
4                NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
             ...           ...           ...           ...           ...   
202451           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
202452           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
202453           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
202454           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
202455           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   

       opertn_22Type opertn_23Type opertn_24Type  
0                NaN           NaN           NaN  
1                NaN           NaN           NaN  
2                NaN           NaN           NaN  
3                NaN           NaN           NaN  
4                NaN           NaN           NaN  
             ...           ...           ...  
202451           NaN           NaN           NaN  
202452           NaN           NaN           NaN  
202453           NaN           NaN           NaN  
202454           NaN           NaN           NaN  
202455           NaN           NaN           NaN  

[202456 rows x 128 columns]
```

I am sorry the .head() is a mess, there seems to be no good way of copy pasting from jupyter cells. You can see there are many Null values.
So when I concatenate the 3 dataframes I do not have any missing data.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index = True)
```

I then use

```
df4.to_csv('all_6years.csv')
```

and it is at this point that the data is lost from df1.

Comment: When you *think* the loss is due to the csv export, test that: Export it and read it into a fresh dataframe. Then check for differences.

Comment: I think thats what I have done in the second heatmap.

Comment: If appropriate, could you show head(10) rows as a sample? and the complete code you used to concatenate and export?